# What is the REST endpoint URL to get the list of site collections in Sharepoint?

Tags: rest, sharepoint

If I go to Sharepoint 2013 site, click on Admin -> Sharepoint, you will see a list of site collections (the link is https://somename-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/SiteCollections.aspx)

What is the REST endpoint URL to retrieve this list of site collections ?

I was trying _api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site' or _api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_web', but it doesn't give the whole list...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to achieve using neither REST nor JSOM.

So, the workaround, as you correctly mentioned in the question would be to utilize `SharePoint Search Query REST/JSOM API` and specify the query `contentclass:sts_site` to return sites results.

The following REST example demonstrates that:

```
function searchSites(webUrl,success, failure) {
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site'";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d.query);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}


//print sites info
searchSites(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,
  function(query){
      var resultsCount = query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.RowCount;
      for(var i = 0; i < resultsCount;i++) {
          var row = query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results[i];
          var siteUrl = row.Cells.results[6].Value;
          console.log(JSON.stringify(siteUrl));
      }   
  },
  function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for Client Credentials Flow (APP level permissions ) What is the solution for those using Client Credentials Flow to get Access token? (meaning App level permissions) sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/150112/…